# Reset Google Maps Street View

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

When you create a street view without any location you get a gray box with the controls.

```
var panorama = new  google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(element.find('.header')[0],{ });
```

Later upon some user action I set the location.

```
panorama.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
```

Great everything works fine!

**But how do I get back to that gray box with the controls overlaid. Reset the Street View so to speak?**

I have a map paired with this and I want the Street View little man with the arrow he stands on to go away as well, this should happen naturally with the reset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set the `visible`-property of the `panorama` to `false`

```
panorama.setVisible(false);
```

When you want to programmatically show the panorama again later, set the `visible` -property back to `true`(this will be done automatically when the user drops the pegman back to the map)